# How do I rebase in mercurial without merging?

Tags: mercurial, merge, rebase

When I try to `hg rebase -s 1775 --collapse`, I am asked to merge all the files I touched since rev 1774.  How can I avoid that?

**Details**

I am just learning how to rebase.  I successfully tried the example given [here](http://seanerussell.blogspot.com/2009/07/mercurial-rebase.html), and a few minor variations.  However, in my own repository, when I try the same steps, I am asked to merge a boat-load of files when I rebase.  Here's what I do.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 hg update -r 1774
 hg tag "Started-New-Feature"
 hg rebase -s 1775 --collapse
```

I thought maybe it was because I had updated to -r1774, so I updated to tip after tagging -r1774.  Same result.

```
hg update -r 1774
hg tag "Started-New-Feature"
hg update
hg rebase -s 1775 --collapse
```

The `hg tag` creates a new rev -r1784.  So I tried updating specifically to -r1783.  Same result.

```
hg update -r 1774
hg tag "Started-New-Feature"
hg update -r 1774
hg update -r 1783
hg rebase -s 1775 --collapse
```

I've searched the web and SO for related questions and didn't find anything, which doesn't mean answers don't exist.  Pointers to existing answers are welcome.

**Edit:**

This seems related [to a reported mercurial bug](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1561) that was fixed in 1.4.  I have version 1.1.  I tried updating to 1.4 or later, but `sudo apt-get install mercurial` says I have the latest, and the download link [on the mercurial page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is currently broken.  So maybe the answer is just getting the latest version, but hopefully there's another way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ubuntu?  If so you can use the launchpad ppa version of hg, which tends to be very currenty https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases

Comment: Thanks.  I cloned the mercurial repository (`hg clone http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable`), and built 1.6.  I will test with that and report.

Comment: Excellent!  Good luck, and keep us posted.

Comment: Unfortunately in the meantime I had to commit the normal way, didn't save the "broken" repository, and now can't reproduce the error.  If/when I ever run into the problem again, I'll report back.